# How to create a closure to use with @escaping

Tags: swift, closures, swift5

I have this function signature on a delegate

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : Any] = [:])
```

I need to create a closure on a Singleton to forward that delegate method, then I do this:

```
typealias sessionDidReceiveUserInfoHandler = (WCSession, [String : Any]) -> Void
var sessionDidReceiveUserInfo: sessionDidReceiveUserInfoHandler?
```

and I use it like this:

```
let mySingleton = MySingleton.sharedInstance
mySingleton.sessionDidReceiveUserInfo = {(session, userInfo) in }
```

Now I have this function signature with the `@escaping` clause

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {
```

How do I do that for that signature. Xcode will not let me to add the escaping to the typealias like this:

```
typealias sessionDidReceiveMessageReplyHandlerHandler = (WCSession, [String : Any], @escaping ([String : Any])) -> Void
```

and if I create a typealias without the escaping it will not let me use inside the function with the error message

> Cannot convert value of type '([String : Any]) -> Void' to expected
> argument type '[String : Any]'

Comment: Your type alias and the parameters for the closure doesn't match,  the closure takes no WCSession as a parameter

Comment: fixed, sorry. Bad copy/paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a return type on the closure (ie inside the last `)`):

```
typealias sessionDidReceiveMessageReplyHandlerHandler = (WCSession, [String : Any], @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) -> Void
```

Comment: sorry, I had a typo on my last typeAlias. This nullifies your answer. Sorry.

Comment: I've adjusted it to match your edited code. The basic idea stays the same -- you're still missing a return type

Comment: @Duck Mistakes in the question do not "nullify the answer". They nullify _the question._ Questioners must take the time to construct the question carefully and correctly.